# User posts will not post but default images will

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a blog type application and in testing I'm inserting a default image in the posts that have no image and the user image in the posts that have uploaded an image. The default images are correctly displaying but I can't get the user images to display inside the post. My logic is to check if the post has a photo_id and if it does, get the file corresponding to that photo_id and display it. The photos are correctly uplaoding to the images folder and the database. Any help showing me what I'm doing wrong so I can learn would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

home.blade.php:

```
@if($posts)
                @foreach($posts as $post)
            <div class="card" style="margin-top: 20px">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div>{{$post->user->name}}</div>
                    <div style="font-size: 10px;">{{$post->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</div>
                </div>


                <div class="card-body">
                    <div>{{$post->body}}</div>
                    <div><img height="200" src="{{$post->photo_id ? $post->file : 'http://placehold.it/400x400'}}" alt=""></div>
                </div>
            </div>
                @endforeach
                @endif
```

Post.php:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'photo_id',
        'body',
        'user_id',
    ];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function photo() {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Photo', 'file');
    }
}
```

Photo.php:

```
class Photo extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'file',
    ];


    public function photo() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

HomeController.php:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();


        return view('home', compact('posts'));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is shown as the `src` when you check it in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the relation before it loading. To load photos

```
$posts = Post::with('photo')->get();
```

Comment: Tried to add your answer and now I get the error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'photos.file_type' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `photos` where `photos`.`file_id` in (1, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30) and `photos`.`file_type` = App\Post)   I am using laravel 5.7

Comment: its because you are using `morphTo()`. If your are using this function you should pass `name`,`type`,`id`. In your case it should be `name`,`post_image`,`post_id`.

Comment: Thanks much. Changing the model to belongsTo fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Use **if** in your blade template.

```
@if(!empty($post->photo_id )) 
    <img height="200" src="{{ asset('/path/to/directory') }}/{{ $post->file }}" alt="">                  
@else
    <img height="200" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">   
@endif
```

Comment: Applied your answer, and now I get little black boxes with X's rather than just blank spaces

Comment: isn't it even loading default placeholder image? And also did you uploaded the file in any folder or saved the images as **blob** in database?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I can see you just want a single result from your `photo` method, I would suggest using the [`morphOne`](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_morphOne) method. Without this the following answer should be altered a little bit to fit the `Collection` return value of the `morphMany`.

As we can see you try to access your photo with:

`$post->file`

However looking at your code the `Post` model class does not have a `file` property. I think it is just a typo and you should retrieve your file like:

`$post->photo->file`

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving images in storage, then you will not be able to access it until you create a symlink to the storage directory by using this command: `php artisan storage:link`. Then you will be able to access it.